# longtable caption is floating over longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

I am attempting to use longtables since my table will span several pages.  The problem I have now is that the captions are floating over top of the table making it difficult to read the table.  I want the caption below the table for each page it is on, but am not sure how to accomplish that.

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\section{System}
\begin{longtable}[H]
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{white}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.20\linewidth}|p{0.80\linewidth}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{cyan}
\textbf{field} & \textbf{value}
\\ \hline
website & http://www.funtoo.org \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Funtoo Details}
\label{Funtoo Details}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Obviously, this is not the table that has too many rows in it, but just serves as an example of the problem.

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable! Inside `longtable` you do not need `tabular`, please check the documentation with `texdoc longtable` ...  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do take some time to master the structure (and syntax) of `longtable` environments:

- Don't use `tabular` environments inside a `longtable` environment. Really: don't do it.
- Don't use `center` environments inside a `longtable` environment -- it's automatically centered (assuming it's not wider than `\linewidth` by design or accident...)
- The full width of your `tabular` is not `\linewidth` but `\linewidth + 4\tabcolsep + 3\arrayrulewidth`. That's not the intention, is it?
- A `longtable` doesn't float -- the `[H]` positioning specifier doesn't do anything at all (other than clutter up the code)

The following may be a useful starting point for further refinements. Note how (a) I've separated out the header, the footer, and the body of the `longtable` and (b) provided calculations for the usable widths of the two columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,url}
\begin{document}
\section{System}

\begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                   p{\dimexpr0.8\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
%% define the header 
\hline
%\rowcolor{cyan}
\textbf{field} & \textbf{value}\\ 
\hline
\endhead
%% define the footer
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\ % blank line
\caption{Funtoo Details}
\label{Funtoo Details}
\endfoot
%% body of table
website & \url{http://www.funtoo.org} \\ 
website & \url{http://www.funtoo.org} \\ 
website & \url{http://www.funtoo.org} \\ 
website & \url{http://www.funtoo.org} \\ 
website & \url{http://www.funtoo.org} \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I had all of those things because I converted directly from my table usage.  Now, I'd like to re-add the colors I had, but that is a minor detail.

Comment: I re-added the colors, so that worked perfectly for me.